# SQL query for adding a column value and renaming

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL table CURR_TRANS and one of the columns ‘CONAMT’ contains transaction amounts -
There are multiple row entries. I’m  looking to do a sum of all of the transactions in that particular column and then rename the output to display as ‘Settlement Amount’ and also show a count of the amount of rows that were present in the calculation.

I.e Count 129 Settlement Amount  1050.00

I’ve reached a point where I can do the SUM (CONAMT) and also the count (CONAMT) and I have a few other dependencies but I can’t manage to group it all together as I need.

Comment: Provide a complete [mcve], and also show us your current query attempt. And add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: Sure thanks. 
I have 2 queries. 

Select COUNT (CONAMT) from CURR_TRANS where date = ‘20240229’ and resp = ‘-1’ and trans_type = ‘700’ and RESPCODE = ‘00’;      Then the other query is select SUM (CONAMT) from CURR_TRANS where date = ‘20240229’ and resp = ‘-1’ and trans_type = ‘700’ and RESPCODE = ‘00’;    And I’d like to join these both together but have the SUM displayed as ‘SETTLEMENT AMOUNT’ along with the count of rows that were present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you described it, it looks as if you just need to use both aggregates in the same query and provide **aliases**; if you want to have two (or more words) or mixed letter case, enclose them (aliases) into **double quotes**.

```
SELECT COUNT (conamt) AS "Count",
       SUM   (CONAMT) AS "Settlement Amount"
  FROM CURR_TRANS
 WHERE     date = '20240229'
       AND resp = '-1'
       AND trans_type = '700'
       AND RESPCODE = '00';
```